# ASP.NET MVC 5 : How to bind multiple resultsets of a stored procedure to different Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

I'm new to MVC. I've a doubt in handling multiple resultsets.

A SP returning multiple result sets. That i need to bind it with different Models.

I can't not use EF.

What is the best possible method?

Example:

```
create proc prc_get_AllProducts
as
begin
     select * from Products
     select * from distributors where id in(select distributorid from Products)
end
```

I need to bind the result of the above procedure to different Models.
    1st resultset should bind to Products Model
    2nd resultset should bind to Distributors Model

Let me know the best Possible way...

Comment: Why are you not creating separate stored procedures for each result set - and have 2 methods `List<Product> FetchProducts()` and `List<Distributors> FetchDistributors()`?

Comment: Try http://automapper.org/

Comment: Stephen, in some cases i cannot split into two.

Comment: Hi Saranya,
I think in auto mapper example, they are not using stored procedures.
Can we use stored procedures?
I'm trying to use Dapper, but that framework also not support my process.
Any other way is there to use SPs?